# Using \tag in \aligned embedded within \equation environment

Tags: equations, align, tag

I want to tag my equations with parallel aligned environments. The code is shown below

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \bold{H}_1^\top\bold{x}_1^*+\bold{K}_1^\top\bold{y}+\bold{U}(\omega_t)= \bold{r}_1:\\
& \bold{A}_3^\top\bold{y}\leq \bold{b}_3:
\end{aligned}
\qquad
\begin{aligned}
& \boldsymbol{\gamma}_1(\omega_t), \\
& \boldsymbol{\zeta}_1(\omega_t), 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
```

The output should be two aligned equations, and my goal is to tag them using `\tag`.

I have tried to add `\tag` to the first `\begin{aligned}` block and the second block, but they all failed with an error saying

> Package amsmath Error: \tag not allowed here

I have searched the forum but there is none regarding to the tag for double aligned equation. I need to use `\begin{equation*}` instead of `\begin{equation}` to allow `\tag`, since I want to make my own tags.

Thank you in advance!

Gabriel

Comment: it's probably easier to just use 2 minipages similar to [Two columns of equations, aligned and just one number per column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114021/117534)

Comment: `\tag` only works in math environment which is normally numbered. like `equation`, `align` etc and not in `equation*`

Comment: Package `mathtools` has the `\newtagform` and `\usetagform` commands if you want to customise tags.

Comment: Simply use `align` and `array` environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe  it is something like this you're after?

```
\documentclass[10pt, a5paper]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tabularx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\hsize=1.2\hsize \compress\arraybackslash}X @{\qquad} >{\hsize=0.8\hsize\compress\arraybackslash}X@{}}
{ \begin{subequations}\begin{align}
& \mathbf{H}_1^\top\mathbf{x}_1^*+\mathbf{K}_1^\top\mathbf{y}+\mathbf{U}(\omega_t)= \mathbf{r}_1:\\
& \mathbf{A}_3^\top\mathbf{y}\leq \mathbf{b}_3:
\end{align}
\end{subequations}}
 &
{ \begin{subequations}\begin{align}
& \boldsymbol{\gamma}_1(\omega_t), \\
& \boldsymbol{\zeta}_1(\omega_t),
\end{align}
\end{subequations}}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]